# Setting Collection List values from property grid at design time in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a custom form where I have a GridView on it. Most of my forms will inherit from this custom form.

so let's say that I have

```
class A : B 
{
  //Contents
}
```

with the above scenario, my problem is: I am not able to edit the grid's columns, 
on the designer view's property grid. it's like they are locked.

so I have decided to create a custom property to set a list of column names etc.

so to do this I have these classes

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(BrowseLayoutColumns))]   
public class BrowseLayoutColumns : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    #region Properties

    private string _columnName = string.Empty;
    public string ColumnName
    {
        get => _columnName;
        set
        {
            if (null == value) return;
            _columnName = value;
        }

    }

    private string _bindingField = string.Empty;
    public string BindingField
    {
        get => _bindingField;
        set
        {
            if (null == value) return;
            _bindingField = value;
        }
    }        
    #endregion
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Columns";
    }        
}

internal class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : class
{
    #region ListMethods
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        ListChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        ListChanged?.Invoke();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;
    public delegate void ListChangedEventHandler();
    #endregion
}
```

and inside my Custom class I added

```
private MyList<BrowseLayoutColumns> _browseLayoutColumns = new MyList<BrowseLayoutColumns>();
    [Category("Design")]
    public MyList<BrowseLayoutColumns> BrowseLayoutColumns
    {
        get => _browseLayoutColumns;
        set => _browseLayoutColumns = value;
    }
```

and inside form Initialization I've created the ListChanged event.

```
private void _browseLayoutColumns_ListChanged()
    {
        if (_browseLayoutColumns == null) return;
        foreach (var column in _browseLayoutColumns)
        {
            myGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.BindingField);
        }
    }
```

so now as you can see below in the design time I'm able to add columns

[image]

the problem here is, it's like the data entered here is not persistent, I mean, it is not adding these values to the columns because my event is not triggered when I run the program and when I debug I see that my BrowseLayoutList property is empty.

any help?

P.S I've tested my event and others by adding to browselayoutcolumns property manually